# Windows command prompt, search for dots

Tags: windows, command

How can I perform this operation? I want to search for `.looking` but the results I get omit the dot. .looking is a css class.

-> grep -Ri ".looking"  public_html/wp-content

Answer (score 0):

As Grep uses regular expressions, you need to escape the dot.

Try the following:

```
grep -Ri "\.looking" public_html/wp-content
```

Also try:

```
grep -Ri "\\.looking" public_html/wp-content
```

Comment: Above does not work... nothing happens. Only ".looking" produces an output. I do not need an answer anymore since I solved my problem anyway. But would still be good to know for the future.

Comment: I searched directly in files.